# Scaling Node instances inside of Docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker

I am setting up my backend that is a NodeJS app running inside of a docker container.

Before my app.js would check the VM it was running on and spin up x number of instances for x number of cores available.

With it now running inside of a docker container, should I be leaving the code in, or will docker manage that itself somehow, and will the node app, be able to see the number of cores available to it?

Here is the code I was working with

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('node-exampleapp');

var cluster = require('cluster')

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Count the machine's CPUs
  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
  // Create a worker for each CPU
   for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
      cluster.fork();
      console.log('Worker ' + i + 'created');
}

  // Listen for dying workers
  cluster.on('exit', function () {
  cluster.fork();
});

} else {
   var app = require('../app');
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the code in.  So far as your app can tell, it is still running on the host machine and it can see the hardware capabilities of that machine.